# How to extract list of distinct key value pairs in a JSON object with BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a BigQuery table named 'my_table' with around 5 columns. One of the columns is 'extra_details' with a JSON data type. The table contains sample rows as shown below:

```
{"name":"mahesh","movies":10,"has_flops":false}
{"flops":false,"movies":9,"region":"India"}
{"sports":true,"countries":10,"region":"India"}
{"movies":2}
null
```

above are 5 example rows to extra_details field
Now, I want to write an bigquery SQL query that lists the distinct key-value pairs from the 'extra_details' field.

below is the approach I'm following:

```
SELECT
  key,
  value
FROM
  `mytable`,
   UNNEST(JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(extra_details)) AS attribute
CROSS JOIN
  UNNEST([STRUCT(JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(attribute, '$.key') AS key,
              JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(attribute, '$.value') AS value)])
```

but the above returns nothing.

Can someone help me on getting the distinct key value pairs from the above json datatype?

Answer (score 2):

The following should achieve the list you are after:

```
SELECT
      KEY
    , value
    , count(*) as c -- optional column
FROM `mytable`
    , UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(TO_JSON_STRING(extra_details), r '"([^"]+)"\s*:\s*([^,}]+)')) AS attribute
CROSS JOIN UNNEST([STRUCT(SPLIT(attribute, ':')[OFFSET(0)] AS KEY, SPLIT(attribute, ':') [OFFSET(1)] AS value) ] )
GROUP BY
      KEY
    , value
```

- REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL extracts all key-value pairs from the "extra_details" column as a JSON string
- TO_JSON_STRING converts the extracted JSON string to a JSON object
- UNNEST is used twice to split the JSON object into separate rows for each key-value pair
- SPLIT is used to split each key-value pair into separate columns for "key" and "value"
- Finally, the results are grouped by the "key" and "value" columns (for distinct list)
- option - you can count the occurrences

You can use `select distinct` instead of `group by`, but group by enables other possibilities.